# Lorentz force (equation)

Tags: electromagnetism, forces

i have a question

When we consider the motion of a particle, then write
ordinary Lorentz force
[image]
Why do not we consider a charged particle's own field, because
it is known, is always much larger than the external field and the even formation
It becomes infinite at the point where the particle is?

Comment: From the particles POV, what's its own (effective) field gonna be? That might help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You can't consider particle's own field because its module will be infinite and it is impossible to state in which direction it is directed. For that field, expressed in spherical coordinates for example, the point r=0 is a singular point and even the force will be infinite and without a definite direction.